# Drawables showing black rectangles

Tags: java, android, drawable

This problem only occurs on random devices. For instance, my G Nexus displays the icons correctly, but my friend's does not.

I have my drawables all stored in the "drawables" folder, not the ones with the specific pixel densities.

It displays other icons correctly. Only the one which I programmatically create with Drawables does it bug out.

The log cat does not seem to throw any exceptions.

For some reason, only on some devices, the icons I try to draw display as black rectangles. This only occurs with icons I first converted into a Drawable. The code I have are as follows:

```
public static class GridItem {
    public String text;
    public Drawable image;
    public Intent intent;
    public GridItem(String text, Drawable Image, Intent intent) {
         this.text = text;
         this.image = image;
         image.setBounds(0, 0, 160, 160);
         this.intent = intent;
    }
}
```

And here is how I create the Drawables:

```
gridItems.add(new GridItem("Schedule", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.schedule),
    new Intent(this, ScheduleActivity.class)));
```

And here is the BaseAdapter class:

```
public class GridMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);
        item.setPadding(0, 50, 0, 40);
        GridItem current = gridItems.get(position);
        TextView label = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
        label.setText(current.text);
        label.setCompoundDrawables(null, current.image, null, null);
        label.setCompoundDrawablePadding(32);
        item.setMinimumHeight(300);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public final int getCount() {
        return gridItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return gridItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably an out of memory situation. Check memory allocations using DDMS.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: Newer version of Android do not like .gif files, so I just converted them all to pngs, and it works fine now.